# Managing width in xml

Tags: android, xml, width

I'm working on my xml file in android studio.

I want to have "surnameEditText" and "nameEditText", [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYRlK.jpg), which have arrows next to them, to have the same width as the input forms that are located below them.

How to do that? This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pozadina"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xyz.ui.RegisterActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signUpTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/signUpTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="#ffffffff"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="#95ffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/surnameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="#ffffffff"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Surname"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="#95ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How much margin you give to your other fields? Set same margin for Name and Surname as well. Right now it's 10dp

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffffff"
            android:ems="10" >

This is my code for input form just below these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top views only have `margin 10dp` and rest of the views have `marginLeft 16dp`. Change top view's `margin` to `16dp` as well.